# XCTAssertEqual test not working in UI test in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I have below UI for which i have written UI test case-
[image]

My test not succeed if I have un-comment commented code otherwise it succeed  (XCTAssertEqual)
May I know how can i check if login button present on screen or not, and why XCTAssertEqual not working

```
func testExample() {

        let usernameTextField = app.textFields["Username"]
        usernameTextField.tap()
        usernameTextField.typeText("abc@gmail.com")

        let passwordTextField = app.textFields["Password"]
        passwordTextField.tap()
        passwordTextField.typeText("abc123")

        app.buttons["Login" ].tap()

                //let loginButton = app.staticTexts["Login"]
                //XCTAssertEqual(loginButton.exists, true)

        app.navigationBars["UIView"].buttons["Back"].tap()


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `buttons` instead of `staticTexts` when looking for the login button. The text label is part of the button component.

```
let loginButton = app.buttons["Login"]
XCTAssertEqual(loginButton.exists, true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
XCTAssertEqual(loginButton.exists, true)
```

use

```
XCTAssertTrue(loginButton.exists)
```

.